# Detect when a function is getting called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are several elements on HTML page which triggers a js function HardCoded().
I cannot modify HardCoded() function.

I want to run some custom js code after the HardCoded() function is getting called. How can I do that? Is there any handlers for js functions?

I'm building a chrome extension that's why I cannot modify page source code.
I have access to JQuery.

One way is to find all elements who are calling HardCoded() and attach events to those elements but I would like to avoid this method.

Comment: Is there a *good* reason you can't modify `HardCoded`?

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406467/can-i-intercept-a-function-called-directly

Comment: If you really cannot, just chain the handler and wrap the hardcoded call in a promise

Comment: what does HardCoded do? Is it making a DOM change that you can watch for? If you cant edit the function to add a callback, then you will need to determine what changes you can watch for when the function fires.

Comment: @SterlingArcher this is for building chrome extension so cant modify

Comment: @Korgrue yes that method is changing the width of div and unfortunately there's no jquery event for div size change :(

Comment: How is the function invoked? Via HTML attributes like `onclick`? Via event listeners like `x.onclick = ` or `x.addEventListener()`?

Comment: @trincot it is invoked by addeventlistener

Comment: So can you change that `addEventListener` callback code?

Comment: Do you even have access to HardCoded? if not... you're options are rather limited. If you do, then you can simply replace it or monkey patch it like anything else.

Comment: @trincot yes but hardCoded method is also getting called internally by other methods

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
var oldFn = HardCoded;
window.HardCoded = function(){
   var res = oldFn.apply(this, arguments);
   // New Code ....
   return res;
}
```

What this does is to create a reference to the `HardCoded` function, redefine this function and then call the old implementation using the previously created reference.

Comment: StackOverflow (too many recursions) detected!  Try to execute `HardCode()`

Comment: Make sure you pass the arguments along

Comment: Still going to say: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: hoisting is why this fails.

Comment: It needs to be declared as `var oldFn = HardCoded;
HardCoded = function (){`

Comment: @epascarello Yes, you're right, the only time I've done this was to override a function defined as a property of an object. I forgot the way functions and variables are dealt with by the engine.